# why am I getting this error

Tags: java

Why Am I getting an error. In eclipse it says constructor call should be the first line. It is the first line. or you can not extend Main?

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

    public class Main extends JFrame{

        /**
         * @param args
         */
        public static void main(String[] args) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            //JLabel testLabel1 = new JLabel();
            public Main(){
                super("title bar");
            }
        }

    }
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your `Main` constructor should sit *outside* of the `main` method. Like so:

```
public class Main extends JFrame {
    public Main() {
        super("title bar");
    }

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //JLabel testLabel1 = new JLabel();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The constructor should be outside `public static void main(String[] args) {`
It's a function and you can't have a constructor inside a function .

Answer (score 0):

You're trying to define a constructor (`public Main`) *within* a static method. That's not valid in Java.

You probably meant something more like this:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;

public class Main extends JFrame{

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    }

    // The constructor isn't *inside* `main` anymore:
    public Main(){
        super("title bar");
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There are multiple errors.

The first error is that you're defining the constructor of the class in a method. This is illegal which results in the compiler complaining that it expected the `new` keyword instead of `public`.
Secondly, `super` class methods have to be called in the first line. But since, the compiler is now confused due to the previous error, it has reported so.

You might also want to improve on the class naming convention. It is very easy to get confused between the `main(String args[]` method, which is the entry point into your code, the `Main` class, and its constructor `Main()` (which would generated by the compiler).

Comment: What should you call your main class? I came from a c background, new to java.

Comment: @Vineet - that constructor would not be generated by the compiler.  A default no-args constructor would chain to the superclasses no-args constructor.  Actually, I can see no real issue with calling the class `Main` either.

Comment: Give it a meaningful name; something as simple as `MyFrame` would help in this case.

Comment: IMO, `MyFrame` is a worse name.  At least `Main` suggests to the reader that this is an entrypoint class.

Comment: @Stephen, it is my understanding that the constructor would get generated. Your second point holds good - if the super class didn't have a no-args constructor, there would have been no confusion.

Comment: What is the convention in the java community if there is any?

Comment: The [Sun Java naming conventions](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/codeconventions-135099.html#367) is used in most projects. There are variants to this, especially when naming interfaces.

Comment: @Vineet - I don't understand your point.  A default no-args constructor is only generated if there are no explicit constructors, and it will only compile if the superclass has a no-args constructor.  THAT constructor (i.e. the one in the OP's code that has been mistakenly inserted in the wrong place) would not be generated as a default no-args constructor.  Furthermore THAT constructor is strongly suggestive that the intention is to set the frame title via the superclass constructor ... which would make a default no-args constructor a bug.

Comment: @Stephen, yes, you would be right if the OP were to create the one-arg constructor. I'm terribly sorry for lacking the hindsight.

Comment: (Continuing) the real confusion is that the OP has got the syntax wrong.  If the superclass didn't have a no-args constructor, the OP would still have got the same compilation errors.  The secondary error about there being no suitable `JFrame` constructor for `Main`'s default constructor would only show up AFTER the syntax error was corrected.  And even if it did show up immediately, it would most likely only have ADDED to the OP's confusion.